# Using toString() form the Object class in java

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyStack {
    private ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();



    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return list.isEmpty();
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object peek(){
        return list.get(getSize()-1);

    }
    public Object pop(){
        Object o = list.get(getSize() -1 );

        list.remove(getSize() -1);
        return o;
    }

    public void push(Object o ){
        list.add(o);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "stack: " + list.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
     MyStack mystack = new MyStack();
       mystack.push(mystack);
      System.out.println(mystack.isEmpty());
     System.out.println( mystack.getSize());
      System.out.println( mystack.peek());
      System.out.println(mystack.pop());

     System.out.println(mystack.toString());
    }
}
```

the problem is when I run this code I get a lot of exceptions and its because of the toString() method, and I don't know what is the problem can you help?

[image: this is the stack trace]

Comment: What is the error ? What do you mean by "because of the toString() method" ?

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: @josh how can I post the stack trace?

Comment: @RS2838484 By using the edit link at the bottom of your question

Comment: @vincrichaud the error occurs when I run this program , I mean when I delete the toString() method call in last line .. the exceptions does not occur ;however, I need to call that method but I don't know why these exceptions occur

Comment: @RS2838484 Please edit your post, and add the stack trace of the error, and add precise which line is causing the error

Comment: You're likely getting a `StackOverFlowError`? - but explain what you hoped to achieve with `MyStack mystack = new MyStack(); mystack.push(mystack);`?

Comment: @achAmháin "MyStack mystack = new MyStack()" is to create the object , then I used that object "mystack" to call  "push(mystack)" method which will add that object to the ArrayList that I declared as a data field in "MyStack" class.

Comment: @josh I  added the stack trace please check it out.

Comment: Your mystack instance pushed a reference of itself onto itself.  The toString() is therefore being called recursively until the Java stack overflows.